# *Name Server* is not a valid nameserver?

Tags: linux, dns, plesk, nameservers

I am using PLESK to create my own Name Servers:
Added two Nameservers:
ns1.mydomain.com
ns2.mydomain.com

Created two A records, pointing to my server IP and to my Name Servers

When I go to my Domain Provider cPanel and type for Nameservers:

> ns1.mydomain.com
>
> ns2.mydomain.com

i receive error:

> ns1.mydomain.com is not a valid Nameserver; ns2.mydomain.com is not a valid Nameserver

How to fix that and how to actually see if I setted up the nameservers correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to register a private/child nameserver at your domain registrar control panel as below.

ns1.mydomain.com - Your server IP

ns2.mydomain.com - Your server IP

Once you have registered private nameserver you can set those nameserver for your domain at domain control panel as below.

ns1.mydomain.com

ns2.mydomain.com

It will take around 24 to 48 hours to propagate. Once you change nameserver you can also check it at below URL. https://intodns.com/

For Propagation you can check at - https://www.whatsmydns.net/